# Convoluted structuring of data frames, including renaming dplyr and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to create code to send out bag orders to different regions. This is only one sub-region as well. I need to do this to many different regions with sub-areas. I have to do this regularly and am struggling to automate this. My first function using the 'rep' command encounters errors. Then I can't put them all together very easily at all. Ideas?

```
x <- c(0,2,1,2)
y <- c(2,1,0,2)
z <- c(1,0,1)
w <- c(0,1,0)
u <- c(1,1,2)
v <- c(0,3,1)

Apples <- data.frame(x,y,c('purple','yellow','green','blue'))
names(Apples) <- c('area1','area2','bag')
Peaches <- data.frame(z,w,u,c('orange','yellow','green'))
names(Peaches) <-c('area1','area2','area3','bag')
Pears <- data.frame(v,c('orange','yellow','green'))
names(Pears) <- c('area1','bag')

naming.fun <-  function(x){paste(rep("Apple",x),collapse=" ")}
```

This causes an error

```
Apples[,1:2] %>%
  mutate_all(naming.fun)
```

Then I'd like to combine it to be like this:

```
new.x <- c('','apples apples','apples','apples apples')
new.y <- c('apples apples','apples','','apples apples')
Apples <- data.frame(new.x,new.y,c('purple','yellow','green','blue'))
names(Apples) <- c('area1','area2','bag')
```

Then do the same thing for Peaches, to finally get a dataset that looks like:

```
new.area1 <- c('peach','apple apple pear pear pear','apple peach pear','apple apple','')
new.area2 <- c('','apple peach pear pear pear','pear','apple apple','apple apple')
new.area3 <- c('peach','peach','peach peach','','')
Final <- data.frame(new.area1,new.area2,new.area3,c('orange','yellow','green','blue','purple'))
names(Final)[4] <- 'bag'

Final

                   new.area1                  new.area2   new.area3    bag
1                      peach                                  peach orange
2 apple apple pear pear pear apple peach pear pear pear       peach yellow
3           apple peach pear                       pear peach peach  green
4                apple apple                apple apple               blue
5                                           apple apple             purple
```

Ideally, then congregating by bags would be even better. So the yellow bags for area1 has the request of two apple/pear bags and 1 bag with just a pear. Within each cell, each bag can only have one of the same fruit, so the excess need to be moved to another bag.

```
new.area1 <- c('1:peach','2: apple/pear, 1:pear','1:apple/peach/pear','2:apple','')
new.area2 <- c('','1:apple/peach/pear, 2:pear','1:pear','2:apple','2:apple')
new.area3 <- c('1:peach','1:peach','2:peach','','')
Final <- data.frame(new.area1,new.area2,new.area3,c('orange','yellow','green','blue','purple'))
names(Final)[4] <- 'bag'

Final

              new.area1                  new.area2 new.area3    bag
1               1:peach                              1:peach orange
2 2: apple/pear, 1:pear 1:apple/peach/pear, 2:pear   1:peach yellow
3    1:apple/peach/pear                     1:pear   2:peach  green
4               2:apple                    2:apple             blue
5                                          2:apple           purple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bags are in a different order (alphabetical) but I think same result.

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(Apples = Apples, 
          Peaches = Peaches, 
          Pears = Pears, .id = "fruit") %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(bag, fruit), names_to = "area") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  count(bag, fruit, area, wt = value) %>%
  filter(n > 0) %>%
  group_by(bag, area) %>%
  summarize(summary = paste(n,fruit, sep = ":", collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = area, values_from = summary, values_fill = "")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  bag    area1                          area2                 area3      
  <chr>  <chr>                          <chr>                 <chr>      
1 blue   "2:Apples"                     "2:Apples"            ""         
2 green  "1:Apples, 1:Peaches, 1:Pears" ""                    "2:Peaches"
3 orange "1:Peaches"                    ""                    "1:Peaches"
4 purple ""                             "2:Apples"            ""         
5 yellow "2:Apples, 3:Pears"            "1:Apples, 1:Peaches" "1:Peaches"
```

Comment: That is great, the only thing is the last summation, for instance, the yellow in area1 should have 2:apple/pear bags, and then 1:pear. So only one type of fruit per bag.

Comment: But now I'm getting into the territory of beggars also being choosers!!!

Comment: Also, what if one of the datasets are blank, like for instance no apples are needed, so the dataset is zero cause it wasn't populated. Then I get an error.

Comment: Happy to think about this more later if you can articulate your important edge cases.  We're not in a position to anticipate those if you don't mention them.

Comment: That first comment has a case shown in the posted example. For the blank, I ran it on my code and one of the datasets "Apples" was a blank dataframe with 1row/1column with the number 0, so it caused an error. I can probably fix those by just creating a dummy dataframe with a zero using the first row of the other dataframe with a value. But then it would really slow down the whole process.